# Does “the correlation of A and B is statistically significant” require both directions?

Tags: correlation

A simple example:

If someone says:”Scores in exam A are strongly positively correlated (with statistical significance) with skill B”

Is this the same as saying “Doing well in exam A (say top 90%) is strongly positively correlated with doing well (say top 80%) in skill B”?

Logically, it feels both are not the same: correlation implies both are more likely to deviate from mean in the same direction, but it just might be that getting below 90% in Test A does not mean one is more likely to be below 80% in skill B.

Am I confusing myself?

Comment: This seems to be more of a thresholding issue than one of directionality. Cor(A,B) = Cor(B,A), but you seem to be asking if Cor(A,B) = Cor(A>X, B>Y).

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Exactly

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can confusing yourself.

Correlation doesn't care which is A and which is B and it doesn't have an order.

> If someone says:”Scores in exam A are strongly positively correlated (with statistical significance) with skill B”

> Is this the same as saying “Doing well in exam A (say top 90%) is strongly positively correlated with doing well (say top 80%) in skill B”?

No. Maybe the people who do well in A (top 90%) do badly in B (>20%), but the people who do badly in A do very badly in B.

When you calculate a correlation, the first thing you do (or can do, there are several approaches) is to standardize the variables - that is, you subtract the mean (ensuring that the mean is zero) and divide by the standard deviation (so the standard deviation is 1). The correlation doesn't care if 90% of people scored more than 90% on A, and 80% scored < 10% on B. They both get a mean of zero.